# Как реализовать коллизию HashMap?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, hashmap

Задался таким банальным вопросом как "*хочу увидеть коллизию своими глазами в 8 джаве*".
Из истоков известно, что **колизия возникает в том случае, когда хешкод одинаковый, но по equals обьекты разные**.

При коллизии, обьект (ключ HashMap-ы) должен помещаться в некую структуру внутри ОДНОЙ корзины. В джаве 8 (на сколько я слышал) в виде красно-черного дерева.

Пример класса:

```
public class Service {

    private int age;

    public Service(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Как видно, *hashCode()* данного класса всегда будет равен единице (для всех его создаваемых обьектов).
Также *equals()* будет всегда говорить о том, что объекты не равны между собой.

Пример реализации:

```
    public class Work {

    private static Map<Service, String> map;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Service service = new Service(1);
        Service service2 = new Service(2);
        Service service3 = new Service(3);
        Service service4 = new Service(4);
        Service service5 = new Service(5);


        map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(service, "empty");
        map.put(service2, "empty");
        map.put(service3, "empty");
        map.put(service4, "empty");
        map.put(service5, "empty");

    }
}
```

Стоит также заметить, как всем известно, что hashCode() + equals() работают *ТОЛЬКО* для ключа в HashMap.

Результат:
[image: Evaluate expression]

Никакой структуры я не вижу, обычная HashMap.

**ВОПРОС: что я упускаю? Как воссоздать коллизию?**

Comment: попробуйте `null` для ключа везде ставить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто то, что Вы видите на скрине, это `map.entrySet()` в режиме debug.
Вам просто нужно посмотреть `((HashMap) map).table`, и тогда наглядно видно, что "корзинка" всего одна.

Это без реализации hashcode

[image: Это без реализации hashcode]

Это с hashcode 1

[image: Это с hashcode 1]

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё понял. Также в дополнение, если table привести к Node[], то можно косвенно увидеть односвязный список при коллизии (до 10 элементов) и B-TREE при коллизии (если элементов коллизии больше 10)

Comment: Интересно. Спасибо за комментарий.

Comment: @Aleksandr попробовал как вы сказали: `((HashMap.Node[])((HashMap) map).table)` не получилось найти односвязный список(